# Create new array with array elements/amounts set by two other arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two arrays in Python (numpy arrays):

```
a=array([5,7,3,5])
b=array([1,2,3,4])
```

and I wish to create a third array with each element from `b` appearing `a` times in the new array, as:

```
c=array([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4])
```

Is there a fast, numPythonic way of doing this with a minimum of looping?  I need to use this operation thousands of times in a loop over a fairly large array, so I would like to have it be as fast as possible.

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [repeat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is what you want:

```
c = repeat(b, a)
```